# Set Property within Eager Loading

Tags: templating, eager-loading

I'm looking to eager load and set another variable within the eager loading. But I can't seem to find out how on numerous guides/tutorials, and the query seems to be slowing the system down a bit.

```
  {% set entries = craft.entries ({
          section: 'events',
          order: 'postDate desc',
          with: ['eventMainImage'],[''],
          relatedTo: category
      }) %}

  {% for entry in entries %}
    --> {% set venue = entry.eventVenueId.one() %}
```

As you can see by the arrow, I'm wanting to set this property, is this possible within an eager load?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eager-Loading is not like a hook or a callback. You wouldn't set variables within it. You'd want to use eager-loading to load your `eventVenueId` then in your loop you'd set the variable a little differently.

```
 {% set entries = craft.entries ({
          section: 'events',
          order: 'postDate desc',
          with: ['eventMainImage', 'eventVenueId'],
          relatedTo: category
  }) %}

 {% for entry in entries %}
    {% set venue = entry.eventVenueId[0] ?? null %}
```

Additionally you could look at eager-loading a [Nested Set of Elements](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/dev/eager-loading-elements.html#eager-loading-nested-sets-of-elements) to further optimize your query if possible with the data you need off your `eventVenueId` elements.